# How to handle addition and subtraction beyond Integers MAX_VALUE and MIN_VALUE?

Tags: java, integer, overflow, underflow, saturation-arithmetic

The following is the piece of code I am trying to implement:

```java
if (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0 && result >= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
else if (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0 && (result <= Integer.MIN_VALUE || result < 0)) {
    result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
else if (n1 < 0 && n2 < 0 && (result <= Integer.MIN_VALUE || result == 0)) {
    result = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
}
```

but I am not getting satisfactory results. For example, -2147483640-10 gives me 2147483646.

I am sure there has to be a more concrete way of doing saturation.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set limits to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE` in case of overflow, you should track if sign of the result has changed to define when the overflow has taken place.

Unless `result` is `long`, there's no need to check conditions like `result >= Integer.MAX_VALUE` in case of positive overflow or `result <= Integer.MAX_VALUE` for negative overflow.

```java
public static int add(int n1, int n2) {
    System.out.printf("%d + %d = ", n1, n2);
    int result = n1 + n2;

    if (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0 && result < 0) {
        result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    } else if (n1 < 0 && n2 < 0 && result > 0) {
        result = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Tests:

```
System.out.println(add(10, 20));
System.out.println(add(2147483640, 10));

System.out.println(add(-10, -20));
System.out.println(add(-2147483640, -10));
```

Output:

```
10 + 20 = 30
2147483640 + 10 = 2147483647
-10 + -20 = -30
-2147483640 + -10 = -2147483648
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as simply as:

```
return Math.min(Math.max((long) n1 + n2, Integer.MIN_VALUE), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

The operation `(long) n1 + n2` ensures that the result is a `long` so that `n1 + n2` neither *overflows* nor *underflows*.

The `Math.max((long) n1 + n2, Integer.MIN_VALUE)` ensure that in the case `n1 + n2` would have *underflow* we get the value `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Otherwise, we get the result of `n1 + n2`.

Finally, `Math.min(.., Integer.MAX_VALUE)` ensures that if `n1 + n2` would have *overflows* the method returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Otherwise, the operation `n1 + n2` will be returned instead.

Running example:

```
public class UnderOver {

    public static long add(int n1, int n2){
       return Math.min(Math.max((long) n1 + n2, Integer.MIN_VALUE), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(add(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 10));
        System.out.println(add(Integer.MIN_VALUE, -10));
        System.out.println(add(-10, -10));
        System.out.println(add(10, 10));
        System.out.println(add(10, 0));
        System.out.println(add(-20, 10));
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
2147483647
-2147483648
-20
20
10
-10
```